# spring cloud config without post /refresh

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I use spring cloud config. Config server gets property from git repo. Client update own property only after I send post request to /refresh endpoint on client. How can I compel client refresh property after config server handle "change property" event?

Comment: check the documentation-

http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/2.0.0.RC2/single/spring-cloud-config.html#_push_notifications_and_spring_cloud_bus

There is something called Spring Cloud Bus. I have never used it personally , so cant advise , but this fits what u want to do.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at it.

Answer (score 1):

spring cloud bus introduced for refresh all the micro-services when we call to "/bus/refresh" endpoint. You try this by exposing "/refresh" endpoint

Answer (score 1):

To reload config files of config server upon changing some parameter. For that you can try programmatic restart option. That can be done by closing the application context and creating a new context from scratch.
That can be done in a following simple way.

```
    public static void restart() {
    ApplicationArguments args = context.getBean(ApplicationArguments.class);

    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        context.close();
        context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args.getSourceArgs());
    });

    thread.setDaemon(false);
    thread.start();
}
```